# Resource for statement about Happy Ending Problem referenced in Arxiv

Tags: combinatorial-geometry, online-resources

[Andrew Suk's Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.08657.pdf) produces an upper bound of size $ES(n) = 2^{n + o(n)}$ for the famous ``Happy Ending Problem'', the minimum number of points needed to force a convex $n$-gon. He also mentions a tighter upper bound (of the same order) on $ES(n)$ by Gabor Tardos. Does anyone know where to find Tardos's proof?

Comment: The section "Concluding Remarks" mentions Tardos's improvement.

Comment: Ask Andrew Suk directly?

Comment: I may be able to ask him directly for you since his office is located a floor above my advisor's.

Comment: so, did you ask?